# how to draw costume number of squares in react native?

Tags: react-native

i want to draw a layout in react native of pressable Rectangles, 
that would accept a costume number to put in the screen.

(let's say i want my view to have 10 Rectangles, so i'd give it 10 and it would stretch this 10 to my screen exactly.) (and later if i change it to 5 it would stretch this 5 exactly to my screen)
and then of course to have them all clickable and to know in the listener what square i'm clicking at.

Do you know of anyway i can do this in react native ?
Thnx !!!

example of when i put 10 rectangles (sorry for bad drawing) >

[image]

example of when i put 4 rectangles (sorry for bad drawing) >

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with array... By setting state to 4 or 10.

```
this.state ={ 
  data: [1,2,3,4]
}
```

> You can use Loop (for, foreach..) or array mapping as below example:

```
<View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'row'}}>
 { 
     this.state.data.map((i,k) => (
       <View style={{flex:1}}/> 
     ))
 }
</View>
```

In other hand and easiest ways.. u can try with some package such :

> React Native Easy Grid
>
> npm install react-native-easy-grid --save

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-easy-grid/blob/master/README.md